# GWT Server side entry point

Tags: gwt, entry-point

I followed these instructions
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/usingeclipse.html

There appears to be no entry point function for the server? How do I run background threads or code not related to the rpc services that the server exports?

For example, what if some embedded database needs to be updated every 5 minutes. So then a background thread would fetch this new data to do the updating

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you want to run in the background? Because that may lead to different answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats not how web applications are supposed to work. Read http://code.google.com/intl/de-AT/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/clientserver.html

Comment: Come on anything beyond a toy web app can't seriously rely soley on servlets.

Comment: why would you start a new thread on the server, every time a user connects to your server and let it rund until all eternity? If you really want to do that you can send an RPC request on your pageload which starts a thread on the server (rember to not use the Google App Enginge for that because it forbiddes threads on the server!)

Comment: What if some embedded database needs to be updated every 5 minutes so that fresh content will be served to RPC requests. A background thread is needed to fetch this new content.

Answer (score 1):

1. GWT is client-side technology and has nothing to do with server-side. You can use any servers-side technology with it. If you use java/servlets then you can optionally use GWT-RPC, which is nice, but not required.
2. Web applications are based around request-reply paradigm: when there is a request, they handle it and send back the reply. Servlets are designed around this paradigm. They are used at some of the largest sites and are not just a toy (as you noted in other comment).
3. When you need something to run periodically, then this is usually the job for [Job Schedulers](http://java-source.net/open-source/job-schedulers). I'd recommend Quartz, which has [great documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/index.html). There is also an example how to [initialize it in servlet environment](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/cookbook/ServletInitScheduler.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run some processing when request comes and potentially include some dynamic parts, you can just make your pages to be JSP or servlets. GWT does not need to be used in HTML files. Just the page served by server need to be HTML. So something like *server side entry point* is either JSP or servlet. Otherwise you need to use PRC. But if you needed to run RPC for every page loaded, you could consider this tip of [embedding RPC in the base response](http://wiki.shiftyjelly.com/index.php/GWT#Speed_up_Page_Loading.2C_by_pre-serializing_your_GWT_calls).